# Best way to reassemble a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Need to reassemble a data frame that is the result of a group by operation. It is assumed to be ordered.

```
   Major  Minor  RelType  SomeNulls
0    0.0    0.0        1       1.0
1    NaN    NaN        2       NaN
2    1.0    1.0        1       NaN
3    NaN    NaN        2       NaN
4    NaN    NaN        3       NaN
5    2.0    3.0        1       NaN
6    NaN    NaN        2       2.0
```

And looking for something like this

```
Major  Minor  RelType  SomeNulls
0    0.0    0.0        1       1.0
1    0.0    0.0        2       NaN
2    1.0    1.0        1       NaN
3    1.0    1.0        2       NaN
4    1.0    1.0        3       NaN
5    2.0    3.0        1       NaN
6    2.0    3.0        2       2.0
```

Wondering if there is an elegant way to resolve it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def refill_frame(df, cols):
    while df[cols].isnull().values.any():
        for col in cols:
            if col in list(df):
            #print (col)
                df[col]= np.where(df[col].isnull(), df[col].shift(1), df[col])
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({'Major': [0, None, 1, None, None,2, None], 
                   'Minor': [0, None, 1, None, None,3, None],
                   'RelType': [1, 2, 1, 2,3, 1,2],
                   'SomeNulls': [1, None,None, None,None,None,2] 
                  })
print (df)

cols2fill =['Major', 'Minor']

df = refill_frame(df, cols2fill) 
print (df)
```

Comment: IT looks like a downward fill for both Major and Minor. Am I Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, You could do a [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) on the specific columns:

```
df.loc[:, ['Major', 'Minor']] = df.loc[:, ['Major', 'Minor']].transform('ffill')


   Major  Minor  RelType  SomeNulls
0    0.0    0.0        1        1.0
1    0.0    0.0        2        NaN
2    1.0    1.0        1        NaN
3    1.0    1.0        2        NaN
4    1.0    1.0        3        NaN
5    2.0    3.0        1        NaN
6    2.0    3.0        2        2.0
```

You could also use the [fill_direction](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.fill_direction.html#janitor.fill_direction) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df.fill_direction({"Major":"down", "Minor":"down"})

   Major  Minor  RelType  SomeNulls
0    0.0    0.0        1        1.0
1    0.0    0.0        2        NaN
2    1.0    1.0        1        NaN
3    1.0    1.0        2        NaN
4    1.0    1.0        3        NaN
5    2.0    3.0        1        NaN
6    2.0    3.0        2        2.0
```